# How to optimize my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection, scope

I just created a javscript plugin that waits for all the images. The following is my current source code.

```
$.fn.waitAllImages = function(options){

    var defaults = {
        speed: 900
    }

    var options = $.extend(defaults,options);


    var preloader = $("<div/>");
    preloader.addClass('moonsPreloader');
    preloader.attr("id",options.id+"-preloader");


    var hideWrapper = $("<div/>");
    hideWrapper.attr("id",options.id+"-hide-wrapper");
    hideWrapper.css("display","none");

    $(this).wrapAll(hideWrapper);

    $("body").append(preloader);

    $(window).bind('load',function(){
        $("#"+options.id+"-preloader").remove();
        $("#"+options.id+"-hide-wrapper").eq(0).fadeIn(options.speed);
    });


}
```

It works, but I have a concern.

As you see, load callback access options.id. `$.fn.waitAllImages` and load callback are two different functions. Does that mean load callback prevents javascript garage collector to clean options.id variable?

Comment: Check my [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) plugin too.

Comment: @alex // haha it is funny. I have a co-worker whose name is alex as well. Thank you for the plugin. I decided to use yours.

Comment: Let me know it works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Garbage collection details are implementation-specific, but yes your `load` function holds a reference to the `options` variable, so it will be available for the lifetime of that function.

This is rarely a problem in practice, but if it bothers you, you can pass a copy of the values you need instead:

```
$(window).bind('load', { id: options.id, speed: options.speed }, function(event){
    $("#"+event.data.id+"-preloader").remove();
    $("#"+event.data.id+"-hide-wrapper").eq(0).fadeIn(event.data.speed);
});
```

Comment: // thank you for the simple, but detailed answer. Yes, it is rarely a problem in practice. I wanted to get an idea by asking a question that involves only few variables. I've never seen {id: options.id, speed: options.speed}function(event){} syntax before. Thank you for that!!! learned!